# CentOS Running on my laptop keeps on turning off VGA

Tags: centos, vga

I recently built a new desktop so I took apart and recycled my laptop to become a home server. I hooked up a VGA cable to it and put it to a old external monitor I had laying around. I installed CentOS. I want to have the laptop output a VGA signal 24/7, so I can read any updates on the progress of certain tasks, however, the laptop turns the VGA connection off after a few minutes, and the only way to turn it on again would be to press a key on the keyboard.

How would I make it so that the connection is always open?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setterm -powersave off -blank 0 -store
```

You probably need to prefix that with `sudo` if not logged in as root.